# Interface and implementation decoupling

Tags: c++

I'm working on an cross-platform embedded project and I don't want to use abstract classes and virtual tables to separate interface from implementation.

I discovered this technique to decouple interface from implementation at compile time:

```
// interface
namespace iot {
template <class platform>
class uart {
   public:
    uart();
    void methodA();
    void methodB();
};

}  // namespace iot

// implementation for avr8
class avr8;
template <>
class iot::uart<avr8> {
   public:
    void methodA() { std::cout << "avr8:A" << std::endl; }
    void methodB() { std::cout << "avr8:B" << std::endl; }
};

// implementation form stm32
class stm32;
template <>
class iot::uart<stm32> {
   public:
    void methodA() { std::cout << "stm32:A" << std::endl; }
    void methodB() { std::cout << "stm32:B" << std::endl; }
};

// chose platform    
using platform = stm32;
//    using platform = avr8;
//    using platform = mock;    // for unit tests

using uart = iot::uart<platform>;

int main() {
    uart u1;
    u1.methodA();
    u1.methodB();
    return 0;
}
```

Is this a good technique?
Is there a simplier method to choose implementation at compile-time (not link-time) without using a templates?

Compare it with this example, which is almost the same, but without templates

```
// implementation for avr8
namespace avr8 {
class uart {
   public:
    void methodA() { std::cout << "avr8:A" << std::endl; }
    void methodB() { std::cout << "avr8:B" << std::endl; }
};
}

namespace stm32 {
class uart {
   public:
    void methodA() { std::cout << "stm32:A" << std::endl; }
    void methodB() { std::cout << "stm32:B" << std::endl; }
};
}

// choose platform    
namespace platform = stm32;
//    using platform = avr8;
//    using platform = mock;    // for unit tests

using uart = platform::uart;

int main() {
    uart u1;
    u1.methodA();
    u1.methodB();
    return 0;
}
```

Neither first nor second example doesn't enforce an interface.

Comment: this technique, called template specialization, seems a very sensible choice for this.

Comment: You don't even need the interface and templated uart implementations. I would implement a templated `platform` class though that provides the types for uart, timers, gpio, ... My `platform<avr8>` would have `using uart = avr8::uart` but the `platform<raspberrypi>` has `using uart = raspi::uart<0x3e201000>` and `platform<rapsberrypi4>` has `using uart = raspi::uart<0x7e201000>`. All Raspberry Pi have the same uart, just mapped at different addresses. So I need the flexibility to have that as extra template parameter there but not for e.g. avr8.

Comment: I don't fully understand you. Can you give an example on godbolt.org, please?